# Updates from FSL mobile flow queued when Access to LWC system permission given to user

Tags: visual-workflow, field-service-lightning, data-synchronization, fsl, system-permissions

I have noticed an issue which is related to delay in Salesforce updates when using a Field Service Mobile Flow. There are two update record elements within the flow and couple of subflows which executes based on the DMLs done before within the flow, data entered by users isn't immediately committed to Salesforce. Updates are queued and synchronized with Salesforce only after the entire flow interview is completed, leading to delays and making the flow to not work as needed.

This issue is resolved by removing the permission set with the "Access Lightning Web Components in Field Service Mobile" permission(like in below image) and allows the flow to work fine.
[image]

In my case it is essential to have this permission for my LWC components.

It would be great if anyone can provide the reason for this or any workaround.